# What will happen if I clear the slots of a form in RASA?

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

I want to iterate over a form until a slot value does not become true.
I know that a form will continue to ask the questions in its required slots until they are filled.

So, if I clear all the slots at the end of the form, will the form start over from the first mentioned slots again?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the slot values in the form validator method and act accordingly based on the values. If you reset all slots on the validator the form will ask again for `required_slots`.

Answer (score 1):

If you clear all the slots (Setting all Slot_Value's to `None`) at the last Slot Validation the Form Validation will start from the first Slot again.